# Is it possible to in put filename in Java before program running?

Tags: java

Usually we do this `$java hashcounter` then system can print what is the filename? and we input the filename. Or we can write the filename like input.txt directly in Java code.

If I don't know the filename. Is it possible to do this?

```
$java hashcounter filename
```

I use Java on Mac. And my program is hashcounter.java.

Comment: Sure. Arguments are passed to the main function (the entry point).

Comment: Given `main(String[] args)`, then `args[0]` would be `filename`.

Comment: I make it thank you !

Comment: You can't give the filename until you know what it is. Using the command line like this is more common than prompting for it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!

So in the case of putting `java hashcounter filename` in the command prompt, you can get the filename argument by adding:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename = args[0];
}
```